# Add hwspinlock Linux Driver to Petalinux project

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, xilinx, petalinux

I would like to add a [hwspinlock like this](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/hwspinlock/stm32_hwspinlock.c?h=v6.3-rc5) to my Petalinux Project for controlling the xilinx mutex on an fpga. [I was able to](https://gitlab.ssec.wisc.edu/nextgenshis/petalinux-zybo-z7-20/-/blob/DualMutexTesting/os/project-spec/meta-user/recipes-modules/helloworld/files/helloworld.c) control the mutex using ioremap and creating a module, but I cannot figure out how to add a hwspinlock driver as a module, do I have to clone the kernel source and add files to the `/root/drivers/hwspinlock` folder? Or is there an easy way like I have been using with `petalinux-create -t module...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I just copied the `hwspinlock_internal.h` header file directly from the kernel that I needed, here is my [spinlock driver](https://gitlab.ssec.wisc.edu/nextgenshis/petalinux-zybo-z7-20/-/blob/hwspinlock/os/project-spec/meta-user/recipes-modules/ofmutex/files/ofmutex.c) and a [test](https://gitlab.ssec.wisc.edu/nextgenshis/petalinux-zybo-z7-20/-/blob/hwspinlock/os/project-spec/meta-user/recipes-modules/helloworld/files/helloworld.c) which works